# Xml searching recursively for a specific value

Tags: c#, xml

In my C# app I am reading an xml document, and in it, are tags containing paths to where .png and .jpg files are being kept. These tags are ,  and .

I could simply create an XmlNodeList object for each of these tags, such as

```
XmlNodeList image = _doc.GetElementsByTagName.("Image");
XmlNodeList background = _doc.GetElementsByTagName.("BackgroundImage");
XmlNodeList foreground = _doc.GetElementsByTagName.("ForegroundImage");

for(int i = 0; i < image.count; i++)
{
   //..code
}

for(int i = 0; i < background .count; i++)
{
    //..code
}

for(int i = 0; i < foreground .count; i++)
{
   //..code
}
```

Clunky, I know. But, is there a way where I can have the application recursively find the tags that contains the word "Image" and return it as a single XmlNodeList? Can it be done? Would this be the best approach? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try an [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) search.

Comment: @JSteward make as the answer so I can mark it as such. I just finished a tutorial on it and it does the trick. Much obliged.